# Have I misunderstood the definition of open set?

Tags: general-topology, definition

The definition Im reading:
[image]

Well, say I had the open set A. Then by definition, if a is an element of A, then the open interval (a- $\epsilon, a+\epsilon$) is also a part of A. So if a+$\epsilon$ is a part of a, then since A is the open set, a+2$\epsilon$ must be a part of A as well. So on and so forth, we get that every number is a part of A. So If A is an open set, then A is a subset of the Reals and the Reals is a subset of A?

What's wrong with this interpretation?

Comment: Just because you have $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)\subset A$, that doesn't mean $(a-2\varepsilon,a+2\varepsilon)\subset A$. It must hold for some $\varepsilon>0$, not for all, therefor where $\varepsilon$ might be small enough to not leave your set $A$, $2\varepsilon$ could be to big.

Comment: but we showed that a+$\epsilon$ is an element of A, then set a_2=a+$\epsilon$ and we add epsilon again and repeat.

Comment: It won't be the same epsilon over and over again, so for different elements of your set you'll be using different epsilons.

Answer (score 3):

For every $a\in A$ there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that...

Element $a$ has "some authority" over this $\epsilon$. It **determines** how large this $\epsilon$ can be.

You could pick one out and denote it as $\epsilon_a$.

Then $(a-\epsilon_a,a+\epsilon_a)\subseteq A$ and taking $\epsilon_a$ small enough we can even have $[a-\epsilon_a,a+\epsilon_a]\subseteq A$.

Then indeed $b:=a+\epsilon_a\in A$, and you can also find an $\epsilon_b>0$ with $a+\epsilon_a+\epsilon_b=b+\epsilon_b\in A$.

But possibly you are forced to take $\epsilon_b<\epsilon_a$ so you cannot conclude that $a+2\epsilon_a\in A$.

---

edit:

Comment: So could I understand the definition as saying, If a set is open, then it will contain separate intervals rather than seperate points?

Comment: What do you mean with "separate intervals" and "separate points"?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing that it says "there exists" an $\varepsilon$. So you cannot just pick any $\varepsilon$ regardless of what $a$ you pick.

Comment: I would rather say that the OP misses the *order* in the statement:  "there exists..for every" is wrong and "for every.. there exists" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

More than that:
The 2 above comments used the notation there exists some $\varepsilon$ for which $ (a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)\subset A$.
I would like to add to that:

---

a. The point $a+\varepsilon$ need not be in $A$.
b. for every $0\leq r<\varepsilon$ $[a-r,a+r]\subset A$

---

In my opinion, it is not only that claim is true for some $\varepsilon$ it is also that the boundary of the interval $ (a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)$ need not be in A.

Comment: You can replace $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)$ with $[a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon]$ and get an equivalent definition of open subsets of $\mathbb R$, so that's not really the problem here. But of course I agree, $a+\varepsilon$ doesn't have to be in $A$ for the open interval being a subset of $A$.

Comment: Yeah, but then you will miss the corollary that every open set is the union of open sets around it's points.

Comment: No, since you got an equivalent definition, you don't miss anything.

Comment: u r correct, i changed.